# Trigger first element in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How can I trigger the first element in ng-repeat. This is my code so far. I want to trigger the ng-click event on load of the page. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="row member-list">
                <a class="list-group-item active" ng-repeat="connect in Connected" ng-click="getChat(connect.TokenId, connect.SessionId)">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><strong ng-bind="connect.SupportId"></strong></h4>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                      <li><strong>Token ID :<strong ng-bind="connect.TokenId"></strong> </li>
                      <li>
                        <strong>Session :</strong> 
                        <span class="Connect" ng-bind="connect.SessionId"><div class="ConnectIcon"></div></span>
                      </li>
                      <li><strong ng-bind="connect.CreateTime">Chat Duration :</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                </a>

              </div>
```

Comment: you want to pass only first element to ng repeat?

Comment: no, i want to trigger this click event ng-click="getChat(connect.TokenId, connect.SessionId)

Comment: Only the first element on the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this,

```
   <a class="list-group-item active" ng-repeat="connect in Connected" ng-click="$first && getChat(connect.TokenId, connect.SessionId)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `$index` as a parameter of your function.

```
ng-click="getChat($index, connect.TokenId, connect.SessionId)"
```

And you need to write conditional check in controller method, this way you will get more control on your view.

```
$scope.getChat = function(i, TokenId, SessionId){
    if(i != 1) return;
    ...
```